# Is ICO a crowdsale or decentralized organization?

Tags: ico, crowdsale

I want to create an ICO for a project in order to raise fund and found that there seems 2 options for me. One is to create a crowdsale and another is to create a Decentralized Organization.

I am confused with the 2 options and want to get advice which one is better to go.Can anyone here provide some advices?

Comment: I think you need to describe your use case before this question makes sense and, because it's likely to be largely opinion based, would not fit in with the stack exchange format, regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICO: Initial coin offering: Doesn't have anything to do with an organization. It can be used by an organization to reward their tokens to members that contribute.